# iReport on linux, setting up JDBC Drivers

Tags: jdbc, jasper-reports, classpath, ireport

I am trying to get some JasperReports working. To build them I am using iReport. 
I need to connect to an MS SQL Server db. In iReport the MS JDBC driver is listed. However when I go to test the connection I get a class not found error.

I have made sure that I have the driver in my class path

```
      echo $CLASSPATH
      /home/USER/dev/jtds/jtds-1.2.5.jar
```

Has any one run into these sorts of issues and found a way around?

Comment: Poor form, but I can answer this my self now. 
Thanks to http://jeffeske.com/blog/?p=157 
Turns out IReport has its own classpath. Should have thought of that.

Comment: If you found the solution, you can update it as the correct answer.

Comment: I'm a noob to this how do I do that?

Comment: Simply answer your own question, and flag it as correct answer by click the check icon.

Comment: Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 22 minutes. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead. 

Will come back later and answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea is "In iReport the MS JDBC driver is listed." Somewhat surprisingly... this means nothing at all.

Well... it means that the iReport team thinks this is a common enough driver that they put it into the drop down list so that you would not have to type it. It does **not** mean that the driver is available.

As Dan has already alluded to in the comments, the solution is to add the relevant .jar file (jtds-1.2.5.jar) to iReport's classpath using the menu Tools → Options. (On OS X it's the menu iReport → Preferences).

Answer (score 0):

go to the ireport there u will see one icon on top and click it it will show paths there u establish a connection to jdbc and add ojdbc 14 jar to it . that's it simple and add that jar to classpath.